# Rails render HTML file outside of 'public'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do something incredibly simple in Rails 5.0.0.alpha: render an HTML file that is not in the `public` directory.

My route is this:

`get '/api/docs' => 'static#documentation'`

And my `StaticController` looks like this:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
    def documentation
        render 'api/documentation/index.html'
    end
end
```

The `index.html` file I want to render is located in `app/views/api/documentation/index.html`.

Whenever I load `/api/docs` in the browser, all I get is a `200 OK` response with a blank page, meaning nothing is rendered.

I have tried just about every variant of `render`:

- `render 'app/views/api/documentation/index.html'`
- `render 'views/api/documentation/index.html'`
- `render 'api/documentation/index.html'`
- `render '/documentation/index.html'`
- `render 'app/views/api/documentation/index'`
- `render 'views/api/documentation/index'`
- `render 'api/documentation/index'`
- `render '/documentation/index'`
- `render file: 'app/views/api/documentation/index'`
- `render file: 'views/api/documentation/index'`
- `render file: 'api/documentation/index'`
- `render file: '/documentation/index'`

etc. What am I missing?

**Edit**: Server output:

```
Started GET "/api/docs" for 198.167.XXX.XX at 2015-11-16 02:07:48 +0000
Processing by StaticController#documentation as HTML
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: What's the server output?

Comment: @Jason See my edit. Like I said in the question, it's a `200 OK` response, no errors...

Comment: I saw that you mentioned that in the question, but looking at the full server output shows us that the `Rendered api/documentation/index.html` line is missing. Also, one way that you can establish if it's finding the file is to rename it and see if you get a "Template is missing" error. If that doesn't throw an error, then you might have a path issue. If you do get that error on renaming the file, then it was in fact finding the file. In that case, try `puts render_to_string('api/documentation/index.html')` and see if the file content shows up in the server output.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having similar problems as OP. If you're using an api_only rails application, make sure your controller inherits from `ActionController::Base` instead of `ActionController::API`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of main application template. you can fix in 2 way, 
1. Check if the `<%= yield %>` tag is in application.html.erb

Or, disable it using

```
layout false
```

in your StaticController

Comment: You know what, I completely forgot to mention that I am using Rail's API functionality (meaning none of these application-level rendering files were generated when the app was created). You are most certainly correct. I am able to serve static files (if I put them in `/public`), but I wanted to put this file behind a controller for authentication purposes. Since I don't have any app-level layout file, calling `render` is absolutely useless. I will dig into this and get back to you. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Okay, can you try this. I assume it looks for erb file. so that we can mention it's static file. render :file => 'api/documentation/index.html'